# Python 3.x change last printed line end="\r" not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print just one line for ffmpeg outputs but it's not working. Here is my code :

```
cmd = 'ffmpeg -i ' + url + ' -t 00:05:00 /home/userxyz/Desktop/myfolder/test.mp4'

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,universal_newlines=True,shell=True)



for line in process.stdout:
    pline = "Recording : " + line
    print(pline, end="\r")
```

I'm running this code on mint os.

Comment: have you checked last symbol in `line`? I assume it's `\n`, try printing `repr(line)`

Comment: Ahh yep it's ending with \n. How should i remove it ? Just regular string slice ?

Comment: @sword1st or `str.strip`. `pline = "Recording : " + line.strip()`

Comment: I'd use `line.rstrip()` to strip only from the right